# Imported class in angular is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I have an npm project with the following structure:

```
app-dep
├── dist
│   ├── bundle.js
│   └── bundle.js.map
├── node_modules/
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   ├── base-component.ts
│   ├── factory.ts
│   ├── app.ts
│   └── modules/
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

My app.ts code has an App class that utilizes all .ts files inside src/

```
export default class App extends HTMLElement { //some-content }
```

I use webpack to build a bundle.js inside the `dist/` folder.

---

I have another angular project where I install this `app-dep` project using

```
npm install --save ../app-dep
```

When I try to use it in my angular component:

```
import App from 'app-renderer/dist/bundle';

ngOnInit() {
    window.customElements.define('micro-app', App);
}
```

I get this error:

Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': parameter 2 is not of type 'Function'
When I try to log it on console, all I can see is undefined.

It seems that I can't import basic functions even.

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: May be I'm missing something. But it seems clear that "MicroApp" is not defined anywhere in the above code hence you get an undefined error. Because the `.define` function takes a constructor function as the second argument. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define

Comment: Sorry. My bad there. I've edited the question.

Comment: Just before calling the `.define` try console.log(App) and see what it says.

Comment: Yeah. It shows up as undefined. I've mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Thats you problem then, the import is not working or the  package linking. You need to see and make sure that works. May be naming the file as index.js might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with the import or the pack, I ellaborate below with the steps to follow.

Also, make sure that you are exporting all the classes that you want to make available from the outside.

For TypeScript libraries

You can simply use "tsc" and then pack the generated code inside the dist folder with "npm pack" and install the dependency in your application with "npm install ".

This may get complicated due to the different module systems and bundlers, check this links for more info on Webpack:

https://marcobotto.com/blog/compiling-and-bundling-typescript-libraries-with-webpack/

https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

For CSS libraries

The "npm pack" has to be executed in the root folder. You may want to process your styles with sass before and only pack the result.

For Angular libraries

By default with Angular CLI when you build a library project the code is generated in /dist/mylibrary folder.

If you want to use that code in other project, the steps are:

1. Build your library with "ng build mylibrary" (add --prod for production).
2. From your library, move into /dist/mylibrary folder and then execute a "npm pack", that will generate a tgz package.
3. From your application in which you want to use the library execute "npm install " to install the dependency.
4. To import code from the library use "import * from 'mylibrary'"

Other option would be using "npm link", that creates a link between your node_nodules and the library code as explained here:

https://www.willtaylor.blog/complete-guide-to-angular-libraries/

That would be the way to go with local libraries, usually these libraries are published into Npm repository (public or private) and installed remotely with "npm install ". These steps are only for local usage.

Comment: But the library that I want to import into my angular project isn't an angular project. It's just a collection of ts files. Since it is not an angular project, I can't use 'ng build'. That's why I use webpack.

Comment: My fault, I assumed it was Angular as it uses Webpack too, but I see there is no angular.json in the project structure. For non Angular libraries we just use tsc compiler and do the "npm pack" in the root folder of the library. Try if that works for you ;-)

Comment: I'll amend my previous answer and ellaborate.

Comment: I get module not found when I try to import it: `import * from 'app-dep';`

Comment: Please check Webpack docs for export and import, if that helps: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

Comment: Added links to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks Dani P. I was stuck with this issue for some days. I followed the marcobotto link, but I was still facing issues. In my subsequent searches I stumbled upon articles telling me to get started with using a starter library. I followed https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-create-a-typescript-library-using-typescript-library-starter and it ultimately led me to the solution. Looks like the world of modules and bundlers is something that I have yet to explore fully